# conditional formatting: shading cells according to time interval

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, date-formatting, vba

I have a table with time intervals as the column header and employee names as the row header. There is a column with each employee's time in and each employee's time out. I want to shade the cells in each row so that if the column header (say 6:30am) is less than that person's time in...its shaded grey. Likewise, if the column header (say 5:30pm) is >= the person's time out, its shaded grey.

The formula I use for this is: for start of day `E$8<$C11` and for end of day `E$8<$D11`

I applied the first formula to the first row, and the second formula to the second row. As you can see, it gets tripped up at the 10:00am column for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I implemented what the answer below suggest I do, and no change :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update the format you're using for Time**
`10:00am` is not recognized as `10:00 AM` by excel, and neither is `8:30am`.  So when you're comparing whether or not `10:00am` is less than `8:30am` with the expression you provided, you're going to get an answer of `TRUE`, because the char order for `1` (the first char in `10:00am`) is before that of `8` (in `8:30am`).

Basically, change your Time values in the 8th Row from `6:00am` to `6:00 AM` etc, as well as the employee clock in and out time values in columns C and D.

You need to have a space between the time and the AM/PM part, otherwise you're not comparing time values, but instead char values, which is why I believe you are experiencing inconsistency in your results.

**In Addition**, try the following formula for your conditions:  `=AND(E$8>=$C11,E$8<=$D11)` in E11

Comment: Hi @Namkce, I edited the table to include your answer and the formula still does not work. I even tried inputting the formula column by column instead of by row, and it still trips up at 10:00 AM. What did I do wrong? I included another picture in my initial question for reference

Comment: @SRag What is the exact formula that you're using?  I am using the following formula (to place in cell E11). 
`=AND(E$8>=$C11,E$8<=$D11)`
Create a new conditional formatting rule for Cell E11 with rule "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", and then enter my formula above, and then drag and apply that condition to all the cells.  See my answer for [Excel Conditional Formating over multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750273/excel-conditional-formating-over-multiple-rows/37751855#37751855) on how to apply the conditional formats to the other cells.

Comment: that worked! I changed it to `=AND(E$8<=$C11, E$8>=$D11)` but your formula works, thank you. I originally had 2 rules, one being `E$8<$C11` and the other `E$8>=$D11`

Comment: @SRag you're welcome; glad to see you got it working!